# Transform RPC-encoded message to MTOM in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, rpc, mtom, wso2-esb

I'm facing this problem while working with WSO2 ESB:

I need to transform a RPC-encoded message which includes a byte array into a new MTOM-based message which contains the ID of that byte array and the binary file as an attachment.

I'd to know if there's any mediator in the ESB to accomplish this task or if I need to create my own procedure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just copy binary data from source message binary field into a target message binary field and enable MTOM in the proxy QoS.

Let me now if if works.